# Latin words remembered from high school 50 years ago

Tags: passage-identification, song-lyrics

Can anyone help with information about the words below, which we sang in language class, which I think was the English national anthem?
Forgive the mistakes, as I never studied Latin.

> *Salve Britanniae, Regina nobilis, … floreat*

I'd be interested in the rest of the song, if anyone can help.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. You've solved a long term query for me so quickly.
Marianne

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you meant

> Salve Britannia, Regina nobilis, ...floreat

which can be translated as

> Hail Britannia, noble Queen, ... may [she] prosper

(thanks to draconis for correcting an earlier error).

*[Salve](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/salve#Latin)* is an expression of praise, or welcoming, or goodbye. *[Nobilis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nobilis)* can mean noble, but also famous. So you would need the full context to asses the exact meaning intended.

Answer (score 5):

The first comma is just phrasing in the tune; it doesn't add to the sense. It may have been

> 'Salve Britanniae Regina gracilis, ..floreat nobilis

(God) save you, gracious Queen of Britain; may she flourish the noble...

Just for comparison, a completely different Latin version of the National Anthem is given at [latinisedhymns.org.](http://latinisedhymns.org.uk/hymn/310)

And here, poems to the **first** Queen Elizabeth by [philological.bham.ac](http://www.philological.bham.ac.uk/schede/text.html)

> **I.** *Silva nemusque virens, et flore fragrantior hortus*
>   Flourishing wood and grove, and garden pretty fragrant wiht flower.

and this, which includes a lady from the poet's private life:

> ELISA claro tota fulgis auRO
>   LImbos et oras. Proxime tuo SI
>   SAltem nitori, en aurea est ROSI NA.